# Want to know something about Ububtu LTS update

Tags: upgrade

I know Ubuntu LTS version supports for 5 years. Previously i used ubuntu 16.04LTS and now upgraded to 18.04LTS. I want to know that whether i again get supports of 5 years or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all 'main' repository software will have 5 years of support  (guaranteed by Canonical).

However note:  if you add other repositories of software (eg. 'universe' or community supported packages), they do not have 5 years of supported life, default is 3 years for packages on install-media for flavors, but you should still check (release-notes).

Also note: not all 18.04 releases were LTS or long-term-support, for example Ubuntu Studio 18.04 was a standard release, but it's 'main' repository packages still have 5 years of support, and the other packages can be extended to the normal 3 years by adding a PPA to your system as has been blogged about recently.  (https://ubuntustudio.org/2019/04/ubuntu-studio-18-04-extended-support/)

The best way to see for your system is to use `ubuntu-support-status` to view the status for packages in your system, eg.

```
guiverc@d960-ubu2:~$   ubuntu-support-status
Support status summary of 'd960-ubu2':

You have 2201 packages (53.6%) supported until July 2020 (Canonical - 9m)
You have 1 packages (0.0%) supported until July 2020 (Community - 9m)

You have 191 packages (4.7%) that can not/no-longer be downloaded
You have 1710 packages (41.7%) that are unsupported

Run with --show-unsupported, --show-supported or --show-all to see more details
```

*Note: i'm on a 19.10 box; why is why dates appear as they do, ie. the 9 months for my 19.10 hasn't started yet*

Comment: Thank you so much for your nice answer and giving your valuable time for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can check what version you have by opening up a terminal:

`lsb_release -a`

Support level depends on the version you are currently using, not the operating system that was originally installed.

Also, "support" in this context refers to your system having supported (up-to-date) packages, not to be confused with "customer support".

For example, A supported version will continue to receive security updates, while those that have reached EOL (end of life) generally will not.  Newer software also may not work as intended on a version out of support.